# How to perform migration of LinkingObject?

Tags: ios, swift, migration, realm, realm-migration

I need to perform migration , without losing parent/owner .How  to do that in migration block?

**Before Migration**

```
class Deck : Object {

    @objc dynamic var name : String = ""

    var cards = List<Card>()

}
class Card : Object {

    @objc dynamic var text = ""

    var parentCategory = LinkingObjects(fromType: Deck.self, property: "cards")

}
```

**After Migration**

```
class Deck : Object {

    @objc dynamic var name : String = ""

    let cards = LinkingObjects(fromType: Card.self, property: "owner")

}
class Card : Object {


    @objc dynamic var text = ""

    @objc dynamic var owner : Deck?


}
```

*In a new version of app when I'm making a new card , I'm setting parent like this :*

```
let decks = realm.objects(Deck.self)
owner = decks[index]
```

***I just need to do this , but in context of Migration :***

```
 let realm = try! Realm()
        let decks : Results<Deck>? = realm.objects(Deck.self)
        do {
            try realm.write {
                if decks!.count > 0 {
                    for indexOfDeck in 0...decks!.count - 1 {
                        if decks![indexOfDeck].cards.count > 0 {
                            for indexOfCard in 0...decks![indexOfDeck].cards.count - 1 {
                                                       decks![indexOfDeck].cards[indexOfCard].owner = decks![indexOfDeck]

                                                   }
                        }

                    }
                }

            }

        }catch{

    }
```

Comment: There's going to be a couple of ways to do this but a question. A Deck typically has a unique set of Cards, Deck being the Parent/owner and the cards belonging to that Deck. So a List represents to-many relationships whereas the LinkingObjects represents the inverse relationship. That's reflected in your first model. In your second model, you're loosing the automatic relationship generation, so if a card is added to a deck, its owner won't be set. Is that really what you want?

Comment: Second Q: The Card class in the first model has LinkingObjects and that means a card could be Linked back to multiple Decks. Is that the case?

Comment: Was your 'Yes' response to my first or second question?

Comment: For Both :)))))

Comment: I just need to make :
let decks = realm.objects(Deck.self)
owner = decks[index]
In order to not to lose parent.
It will work as I am expecting.I have already checked it. I used for this purpose (for index in 0..decks.count).

Comment: do {
            try realm.write {
                if decks!.count > 0 {
                    for indexOfDeck in 0...decks!.count - 1 {
                        if decks![indexOfDeck].cards.count > 0 {
                            for indexOfCard in 0...decks![indexOfDeck].cards.count - 1 {
                                                       decks![indexOfDeck].cards[indexOfCard].owner = decks![indexOfDeck]

                                                   }
                        }

                    }
                }

            }

        }

Comment: It is all I need.But in context of migration.

Comment: If have additional information to add, please add it to the question which makes it clearer. Especially code as it's hard to read in-line.

Comment: Sorry , I've just done it.

Comment: Jay ,please could you help me?How to write migration block ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The challenge with this question is that LinkingObjects are not persisted - they are calculated so they cannot be directly migrated.

The second challenge is the original card objects doesn't have any persisted properties other than the 'text' var.

Here's the code that will does the job. We are getting the new Decks *cards* property, iterating over them and updating each owner property in the Card object to point back to the new Deck.

As soon as a card's owner property is set to that deck, that Decks linkingCards property will 'pick that up' because it's calculated.

```
let vers = UInt64(1)
let config = Realm.Configuration( schemaVersion: vers, migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
     print(oldSchemaVersion)
     if (oldSchemaVersion < vers) {
        print("  performing migration")

         migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: Deck.className()) { oldDeck, newDeck in
            let cards = newDeck!["cards"] as! List<MigrationObject>
            for card in cards {
                card["owner"] = newDeck
            }
         }
     } else {
        print("no migration needed")
    }
 })
```

My Original objects look like this, which should match the ones in the Question

```
class Deck : Object {
    @objc dynamic var name : String = ""
    var cards = List<Card>() //current
}

class Card : Object {
    @objc dynamic var text = ""
    var parentCategory = LinkingObjects(fromType: Deck.self, property: "cards") //current
}
```

and then the updated objects look like this

```
class Deck : Object {
    @objc dynamic var name : String = ""
    var cards = List<Card>() //current
    let linkingCards = LinkingObjects(fromType: Card.self, property: "owner") //new
}

class Card : Object {
    @objc dynamic var text = ""
    var parentCategory = LinkingObjects(fromType: Deck.self, property: "cards") //current
    @objc dynamic var owner : Deck? //new
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jay , but I am getting error " Could not cast value of type 'RLMResults' (0x1053c7e88) to 'RealmSwift.List<RealmSwift.DynamicObject>' (0x7fff89e4b968) "

Comment: @FilipCernov Hmm. I literally copy and pasted that code from a fully functional project. Perhaps one of the var names was changed or maybe you are running an old version of Realm? This is macOS Catalina, XCode 11 and Realm 4.1.1.  I included my models in my answer so check them out. Note that my updated models included the prior model vars so they could be accessed during the migration. Don't forget LinkingObjects are calculated, not persisted.